# Angular $q.all() only pass the first result to then

Tags: http, angularjs, promise

As stated in the title, when I call `$q.all()` with two promises, I only receive the first result. this is what I am doing:

```
$q.all(resouce1.getAll(), resource2.getAll()).then(function (res1, res2) {
    // only output one object which contains the result from the first promise
    // if I swap the two promise, the result is still the first one.
    // can't really get both results at the same time
    console.log(arguments);     
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$q.all([resouce1.getAll(), resource2.getAll()]).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);     
});
```

`all` accepts an array or hash of promises, and then calls a function with a single array result.

Comment: :). awesome. I missed the point of passing an array instead. thank you so much man.